Using trigonometry, how to I find the area and the perimeter of this triangle?

This is a problem that came in a math competition that I took. In this scenario, I need to find the area and perimeter of the triangle here in this image, where $AB$ is $3x-5$, $BC$ is $3x-4$, and $AC$ is $3x-3$.
I first started with drawing a line bisecting $\angle ABC$ that divides it into $2$ triangles. This was a trick for another problem which I made, but I don't know how to proceed further, like by finding the lengths. This is because even though $\angle A+\angle C=60^\circ$, I need to find the individual lengths of each side to find some sort of ratio between the sides. Trigonometry is preferred, but any help is appreciated.

My first try, which might not succeed, would be to use the Law of Cosines to solve for $~x,~$ and then use Heron's Formula to compute the area.

Using the cosine rule,
$$(3x-4)^2+(3x-5)^2-2(3x-4)(3x-5)\cos120^\circ=(3x-3)^2$$
$$\implies 18x^2-63x+52=0$$
$$\implies x=\frac{63\pm\sqrt{225}}{36}$$
$$\implies x=\frac43,\frac{13}6$$
Since the lengths of the sides of a triangle must be positive and the sum of any $2$ sides must be greater than the third, we require $x>2$, i.e., therefore the solution is $x=\frac{13}6$ only. So, the perimeter of the triangle is
$$p=9x-12$$
$$\implies\boxed{p=\frac{15}2\text{ units}}$$
Then, to find the area of the triangle, use the formula
$$\Delta=\frac12ac\sin B$$
$$\implies\Delta=(3x-4)(3x-5)\frac{\sqrt3}4$$
$$\implies\boxed{\Delta=\frac{15\sqrt3}{16}\text{ sq. units}}$$
